# PHP PDO connection failing without error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

It's been many years since I did any dev in PHP.
The concept of connecting to MySQL using PDO is completely new to me, and I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

Using MySQLi, and the following code, which I know is deprecated, works nicely:

```
<?php
include 'models/db_details.php';

$db_connection = mysql_pconnect("$dbhost", "$dbusername", "$dbpasswd") or die("Couldn't connect to server: " . mysql_error());

$db = mysql_select_db("$dbname", $db_connection) or die("Couldn't select database.");
?>
<h1>After connecting to the DB</h1>
```

As expected, this displays:

> After connecting to the DB

From all of the pages I have read, using PDO, this should look something like:

```
<?php

include 'models/db_details.php';

try 
{
    $conn = new PD0("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $dbusername, $dbpasswd);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
<h1>After connecting to the DB</h1>
```

The result of this is a completely blank page.

All of this is on a FreeBSD box, running:
Apache/2.4.25
PHP/5.6.30
MySQL 5.6.35

I have uncommented extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll in php.ini.

I can also confirm that the MySQL driver for PDO is installed:
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: _The result of this is a completely blank page._ - let us know what's error message you get (check your logs, or enable display_errors)

Comment: As a note, `mysqli` is not deprecated, but the `mysql_pconnect` function you're using there is, and that's a different family of functions.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about display_errors.  It turns out the IDE I was using (Visual Studio Code) defaulted to using 'Droid Sans Mono', which displays very little difference between zero, and capital 'o'.  Rather than having PD(capital 'o'), I had PD(zero).  Default font changed to DejaVu Sans Mono, problem solved.

Comment: @PeterTipping this is a typo, you can delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the font.  Make sure it is pdo and not pd0 (zero).

Magic happens after that.